# Why define TP_ARGS in TRACEPOINT_EVENT_CLASS and in TRACEPOINT_EVENT_INSTANCE both?

Tags: lttng

I'm currently using LTTng for such performances issues, and I want to use `TRACEPOINT_EVENT_CLASS` and `TRACEPOINT_EVENT_INSTANCE` as well.

But I don't understand the 2.10 version's [documentation](https://lttng.org/man/3/lttng-ust/v2.10/#doc-example). I wonder why we need to define `TP_ARGS` in each event instance as well as defining it in the event class.
Because we can't modify `TP_FIELDS` to change the type of  any field, or compose it from many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The `TP_ARGS()` portion of a `TRACEPOINT_EVENT_INSTANCE` is used to validate that each instance matches the `TRACEPOINT_EVENT_CLASS`. [See ust-tracepoint-event.h](https://github.com/lttng/lttng-ust/blob/2df82195d140b39c40abfb43d526804a9d14d3da/include/lttng/ust-tracepoint-event.h#L124) for more context.

I recommend that you repost your question on our [mailing list/irc channel](https://lttng.org/community/#where) so that we can have an actual discussion regarding this. The maintainer of lttng-ust and lttng-modules, [Compudj](https://github.com/compudj) will surely provide more context and might even be open to the introduction of a new macro allowing event instance declaration without the `TP_ARGS()` portion.